# Updating multiple rows gives error, trying ON DUPLICATE KEY

Tags: php, sql, mariadb

Im making the user able to sort his own data. Lets say I have multiple animals in each row, with its own Uniqe Id. Then I let the user sort the animals with a number from 1 to x. 
So to do this I have to update multiple rows in my sql-table. I made `Id` uniqe. And then I tried this sql-sentence (this is what the sql is trying to run, my actual php-code is below this code)

```
 INSERT INTO boka_homeworktasks (Id,Sort) VALUES (29 ,1),(38 ,2),(30 ,3),(31 ,4),(32 ,5),(33 ,6),(34 ,7),(35 ,8),(36 ,9),(37 ,10),(39 ,11),(40 ,12),(41 ,13),(42 ,14),(43 ,15),(44 ,16),(45 ,17) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Sort=VALUES(1),Sort=VALUES(2),Sort=VALUES(3),Sort=VALUES(4),Sort=VALUES(5),Sort=VALUES(6),Sort=VALUES(7),Sort=VALUES(8),Sort=VALUES(9),Sort=VALUES(10),Sort=VALUES(11),Sort=VALUES(12),Sort=VALUES(13),Sort=VALUES(14),Sort=VALUES(15),Sort=VALUES(16),Sort=VALUES(17);
```

actually my code looks like this:

```
        $arrsorter = $_POST["sorter"];
        for ($x=0;$x < count($arrsorter);$x++){
            $sql_sentence .= '(?,' . ($x + 1) . '),';
            array_push($arrparams, $arrsorter[$x] );
            $sql_sentence2 .= 'Sort=VALUES('. ($x + 1) .'),';
        }
        $sql_sentence = 'INSERT INTO boka_homeworktasks (Id,Sort) VALUES '. substr($sql_sentence,0,-1) .' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE '. substr($sql_sentence2,0,-1) . ';' ;
        $sql = $conn->prepare($sql_sentence);
        $sql->bind_param(str_repeat("i", count($arrparams)), ...$arrparams);
        $sql->execute();
```

and I get this errors:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in myfile.php:35 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in myfile.php on line 35

Line 35 is `$sql->bind_param(str_repeat("i", count($arrparams)), ...$arrparams);`

I cant see anything I have done wrong, can you? Why cant I update my table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way to do this is:

```
        $arrsorter = $_POST["sorter"];
    for ($x=0;$x < count($arrsorter);$x++){
        $sql_sentence .= '(?,' . ($x + 1) . '),';
        array_push($arrparams, $arrsorter[$x] );
        $sql_sentence2 .= 'Sort=VALUES(Sort),'; //It should not be a value, but refer to a column!
    }
    $sql_sentence = 'INSERT INTO boka_homeworktasks (Id,Sort) VALUES '. substr($sql_sentence,0,-1) .' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE '. substr($sql_sentence2,0,-1) . ';' ;
    $sql = $conn->prepare($sql_sentence);
    $sql->bind_param(str_repeat("i", count($arrparams)), ...$arrparams);
    $sql->execute();
```

The only thing I changed was this:`$sql_sentence2 .= 'Sort=VALUES(Sort),';`

Answer (score 0):

This error means, that '$conn->prepare($sql_sentence);' returns FALSE. It means that you got an error on execution of '$conn->prepare($sql_sentence)' (almost alwayt it is a syntax errors in the SQL query). I think, that you are using PDO, so for more information just take a look into documentation http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php